# Good alternative to GenuineChannels for .net remoting

Tags: .net, remoting, genuinechannels

We have been using GenuineChannels in our product for the last 4 years. GenuineChannels now appears to have become unsupported and the main developer guy Dmitri has I think joined Microsoft. I have the source as part of the product but not the networking / .net knowledge to support it.

Has anyone found a good alternative to GenuineChannels for good .net remoting? I need our software product to run on top of some supported software!

Answer (score 2):

WCF, Windows Communication Foundation is the approach you should look into. WCF integrates web services, .net remoting, distributed transactions and message queuing into a common communications model.

Getting started with WCF is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx

The tutorial is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx

Oreilly has a book about WCF: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596526993/

Answer (score 2):

There is a product called [DotNetRemoting](http://www.dotnetremoting.com/) that claims to be an easy replacement for GenuineChannels. They even have a [section of their forum](http://www.dotnetremoting.com/ForumView.aspx?ItemID=6&mid=2&pageid=7) dedicated to converting from GenuineChannles to DNR.

Answer (score 1):

WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) is the way to go - much more scalable, easily swappable to other technologies (if you need in the future), and builtin to .NET 3.0.
A lot of other nice stuff there, too... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx